# How to import and use user defined enum classes in robot framework using python

Tags: python, enums, robotframework

I am currently implementing some test cases in robot framework. Assertion checks that the integer is working. I want to change that to enum values. This is my basic requirement.

This is the robot file that I am using (`TestCase.robot`)

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Wrapper.py

*** Test Cases ***
TC_01
    ${rv}    Set Variable    ${0}    #${}
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rv}    0
```

In the line `Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rv}    0`, instead of this integer value `0` assertion , I want to convert that integer to some enum value.

something like this.

```
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rv}    Status.OK
```

where `Status` is a enum class which is defined in the `Wrapper.py`. This `Wrapper.py` is included in the `TestCase.robot` as a `Library` in this *robot* file. I can paste the content of that enum here

```
class Status(Enum):
    OK = 0
    NOT_OK = 1
```

so that instead of integers we can make it more readable. When I give like this I am getting error as

```
'(Status.OK)' cannot be converted to an integer: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(status.ok)'
```

Can you guys help to sort out this issue ?

Comment: The case matters when directly referencing python code; have you tried `${Status.OK}`? Also, it would help if your question included a proper [mcve] rather than several small blocks of data.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the comment. But I am working on a hardware. That's why I can't post the entire thing. I tried this. But it didn't work,

Comment: I never asked for the entire thing. I asked for a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley: Now I updated the code. Now it is minimum reproducible. You just need to have `TestCase.robot` and a `Wrapper.py` and the contents are same as I posted.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things - first and foremost, you want to compare the value, which is the `Enum.member_name.value` property, as already pointed out.
The other things - python Enum is a bit special, it's not instantiated - which would stop you from importing a module having it as class with the same name (to directly reference it) - Robot Framework makes an instance of the class in those imports. So direct access to the value is not possible.

There is a solution, though - make a wrapper (function, in my sample here, but can be a sibling class'es method) that will return you the target value. Sample python:

```
def return_enum_value(member):
    return Status[member].value


class Status(Enum):
    OK = 0
    NOT_OK = 1
```

And the RF usage:

```
${the value}=    Return Enum Value  OK
Should Be Equal As Integers         0    ${the value}
```

Comment: I wll try this solution

Comment: So how did it go? With this approach, the `return_enum_value` becomes an "interface" to the enum - you can get the value for any target defined in it.

Comment: We tweaked this in another way. But I tried your solution. But I was getting `No keyword with name 'return_enum_value' found.`

Comment: @TodorMinakov, your above solution worked for me. Though my requirement was to have str Enum instead of int Enum. The statement `return Status[member]` also works in place of `return Status[member].value`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a solution exactly as you want - that is being able to write `${Status.OK}`. At least I didn't make it work after some time spent messing around with it. If there's actually a solution, please let me know in the comment section.

Also, if I write just:

```py
from enum import Enum


class StatusEnum(Enum):
    OK = 0
    NOT_OK = 1


print(StatusEnum.OK)
```

it will print out `StatusEnum.OK`, not `0` as you perhaps expect. You'd need to write `Status.OK.value` to get `0`. More on that in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

So, the closest I was able to do this is this:

**Status.py**

```
from enum import Enum
from robot.api.deco import library, keyword


class StatusEnum(Enum):
    OK = 0
    NOT_OK = 1


@library
class Status:

    @keyword
    def status_ok(self):
        return StatusEnum.OK.value

    @keyword
    def status_not_ok(self):
        return StatusEnum.NOT_OK.value
```

And in RF:

```
*** Settings *** 
Library    Status.py

*** Test Cases ***
Check OK And NOT OK
    ${OK}=    Status Ok
    ${NOT_OK}=    Status Not Ok
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${OK}    0
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${NOT_OK}    1
```

But that honestly feels like too much trouble when I can just do:

```
*** Variables ***
${OK}=    0
${NOT_OK}=    1

*** Test Cases ***
Check OK And NOT OK  
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${OK}    0
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${NOT_OK}    1
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. I'll try this . The code I am mentioned in the question is reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is relevant to someone but I was able to use enums this way:

**my_enum.py:**

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    FOO = 1
    BAR = 2
```

**enum_suit.robot:**

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    my_enum.py

*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    Check Enum

*** Keywords ***
Check Enum
    Log To Console    ${MyEnum.FOO.value}  =>  1
```